# tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNAuthenticationException: svn: E170001

Tags: maven, svn, jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

We are working n a legacy project (maven) to setup devop. Starter with jenkins. Jenkins build is now without issues. But, while integrating sonarqube with jenkins, we are getting the following error:

```
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error when executing blame for file src/main/java/com/acme/acq/scavenger/AssetCmboItem.java
    at org.sonar.plugins.scm.svn.SvnBlameCommand.blame(SvnBlameCommand.java:100)
    at org.sonar.plugins.scm.svn.SvnBlameCommand.blame(SvnBlameCommand.java:59)
    at org.sonar.batch.scm.ScmSensor.execute(ScmSensor.java:84)
    at org.sonar.batch.sensor.SensorWrapper.analyse(SensorWrapper.java:57)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:58)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:50)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.PhaseExecutor.execute(PhaseExecutor.java:102)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:185)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:120)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:264)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:259)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:249)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.startComponents(ProjectScanContainer.java:127)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:120)
    at org.sonar.batch.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:55)
    at org.sonar.batch.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:120)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:122)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:119)
    at org.sonar.runner.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:61)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:274)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedRunner.java:165)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedRunner.java:152)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.runAnalysis(Main.java:133)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:82)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:66)
Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNAuthenticationException: svn: E170001: Authentication required for '<http://localhost:80> Subversion Project1 repository'
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.authenticationFailed(SVNErrorManager.java:47)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.authenticationFailed(SVNErrorManager.java:41)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.DefaultSVNAuthenticationManager.getFirstAuthentication(DefaultSVNAuthenticationManager.java:203)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:716)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:398)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:386)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.performHttpRequest(DAVConnection.java:720)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.exchangeCapabilities(DAVConnection.java:634)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.open(DAVConnection.java:109)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.openConnection(DAVRepository.java:1044)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.hasCapability(DAVRepository.java:872)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.io.SVNRepository.assertServerIsMergeInfoCapable(SVNRepository.java:787)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.io.SVNRepository.getFileRevisions(SVNRepository.java:756)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNLogClient16.doAnnotate(SVNLogClient16.java:1389)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNLogClient16.doAnnotate(SVNLogClient16.java:291)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.old.SvnOldAnnotate.run(SvnOldAnnotate.java:45)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.old.SvnOldAnnotate.run(SvnOldAnnotate.java:17)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnOperationRunner.run(SvnOperationRunner.java:21)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.run(SvnOperationFactory.java:1235)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperation.run(SvnOperation.java:294)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNLogClient.doAnnotate(SVNLogClient.java:295)
    at org.sonar.plugins.scm.svn.SvnBlameCommand.blame(SvnBlameCommand.java:98)
    ... 34 more
```

Have seen a some discussions related to this error, but in our case none of them are helping us to solve this error like, in %APPDATA%\Subversion\servers file - in the global section have added

```
[global]
# http-proxy-exceptions = *.exception.com, www.internal-site.org
# http-proxy-host = defaultproxy.whatever.com
# http-proxy-port = 7000
# http-proxy-username = defaultusername
# http-proxy-password = defaultpassword
# http-compression = no
# No http-timeout, so just use the builtin default.
# No neon-debug-mask, so neon debugging is disabled.
# ssl-authority-files = /path/to/CAcert.pem;/path/to/CAcert2.pem
#
# Password / passphrase caching parameters:
# store-passwords = no
# store-ssl-client-cert-pp = no
# store-plaintext-passwords = no
# store-ssl-client-cert-pp-plaintext = no
http-auth-types=Basic
```

We are running the whole setup [subversion,jenkins,sonarqube]from a single test box for now(windows 7). Any pointers will be helpful for us to proceed further.

Thanks,
San

Comment: The book's a good bit out of date. Purposely removed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just found that by Disabling the SCM sensor configuration we can avoid this error
[image]

But not sure about the impact (by disabling the blame information retrieval), however the the current setup works as expected.

Comment: **SonarQube** cannot assign issues to authors (of the "_incorrect_" code) if blame information has been disabled.

Comment: This worked for me, disable here and also add property in sonar-project.properties sonar.scm.disabled=true

Answer (score 0):

I face the same issue and obviously the @Kallada's answer works but as @agabrys mentioned in comment there can be some other issues due to this.

So it's better to send this flag key from the caller side.

I used it as below as part of Jenkins script.

```
mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.scm.disabled=True
```

I hope this saves someone's time.